# the array have numbers of items, then loops for set numbers of times in python

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, loops, arraylist

```
['LED_ON', 'Dummy', 'LED_INTENSITY']
```

I have an array with set numbers of items now there is 3 but it could be more or less. Then I want to run something by looping it for set amount of times, there is 3 items in the array so loops 3 times

how I get my array

```
subtest=[]
with open(st,'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        if line.startswith("   subtest"):
            subtest.append(line[12:-2])
        
    f.close()
print(subtest)
```

this is my file

```
   functional

   subtest "LED_ON"
      wire "PSOC_HB_R"    to 204152 aux alternate
      wire "PWR_PSOC_LED" to 205152 source
      wire "LED1-OUT-1"   to 216103 detector high
      wire "SENSOR-GND"   to  21606 detector low
   end subtest

   subtest "Dummy"
      wire "PWR_PSOC_LED" to 205152 aux
      wire "PSOC_HB_R"    to 204152 source alternate
   end subtest

   subtest "LED_INTENSITY"
      wire "PSOC_HB_R" to 204152 aux alternate
      wire "PWR_PSOC_LED" to 205152 source
      wire "LED1-INTENSITY-1" to  21603 detector high
      wire "SENSOR-GND" to  21606 detector low
   end subtest
```

and for the loop

```
import re
#get data from wirelist.dat 
src_map = {}
in_test = False
with open(st,'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        if (line.strip() == '') : 
            #print ('blank line')
            continue
        if (not in_test) and not re.match("\s+subtest\s+\""+info+"\"",line): # skip
            print ('not in test, skip')
            continue
        elif re.match("\s+subtest\s+\""+info+"\"",line):
            print ('found subtest start')
            in_test = True
            continue
        elif (in_test) and ("end subtest" in line):
            print ('found subtest end')
            in_test = False
            break
        elif not (in_test):
            print ('not in test')
            continue
        else: # must be good line in LED subtest
            print ('good line')
            m = re.match(r"\s+wire\s+(\"[^\"]+\")\s+to\s+(\d+)\s+(aux alternate|aux|source|source alternate|detector high|detector low).*", line)
            if not m: # not a line we are interested in
                continue
            else:
                print (m)
                term1 = m.group(1)
                term2 = m.group(2)
                term3 = m.group(3)
                if term3.startswith('aux'):
                    src_map ['a'] = term1
                elif term3 == 'source' :
                    src_map ['s'] = term1
                elif term3.endswith('high'):
                    src_map ['i'] = term1
                else:
                    src_map['l'] = term1
print(src_map)

#find the data that want to be replace
in_test = False
lines_out = []
with open(file,'r') as input_file:
    for line in input_file:
        #print (line)
        if (line.strip() == '') : 
            #print ('blank line')
            continue
        if (not in_test) and not re.match("subtest\s+\""+info+"\"",line): # skip
            print ('not in test, skip')
            lines_out.append(line)
        elif re.match("subtest\s+\""+info+"\"",line):
            print ('found subtest start')
            in_test = True
            lines_out.append(line)
        elif (in_test) and ("end subtest" in line):
            print ('found subtest end')
            in_test = False
            lines_out.append(line)
        elif not (in_test):
            print ('not in test')
            lines_out.append(line)
        else: # must be good line in LED subtest
            print ('good line')
            m = re.match(r"\s+connect\s+(\w)\s+to\s+pins\s+(\d).*", line)
            if not m: # not a line we are interested in
                lines_out.append(line)
            else:
                print (m)
                term1 = m.group(1)
                term2 = src_map[term1]
                #map to wire values using connection type
                
                new_line = f"   connect {term1} to nodes {term2}\n"
                lines_out.append(new_line)

#replace data                
with open('mynewfile.dat','a') as outfile:
    outfile.writelines(lines_out)
    outfile.close()
```

in my loop there is `info` in it and i wan to replace it with the item in my array. For example, first loop will be subtest[0] the second loop will be subtest[1] and so on.

It would be great if you can give me some idea because i have been stuck here for 3 days and still no result and i have never seen anyone use this kind of loop (well I have only
start programming and learning programming for 3 weeks so please help me out)

Comment: What is the goal of the code? Looping it 3 times for what purpose? What do you want to replace using regex?

Comment: sorry `line.split()` is from when i am trying new thing and for got to delete

Comment: the thing that i wan to replace works all i need to do is loop 3 time and change the info to the 3 items

Comment: if you want to see what i want to replace.wait let me edit and put it in
they are almost the same so i thought there no point in putting it in

Comment: sry my brain thermal throttle, the code are connected

Comment: noting in your file will ever match `m = re.match(r"\s+connect\s+(\w)\s+to\s+pins\s+(\d).*", line)` from the 2nd part of your code. You should read about re.sub() to replace stuff in a file. Try to condense your example to a [mre] or see if the answer below already helps you  out. Walls of code often do not get answered/downvoted as they do not follow [ask] and [mre].

Comment: `m = re.match(r"\s+connect\s+(\w)\s+to\s+pins\s+(\d).*", line)` is from another text file. i wan to  try condense my example to a minimal reproducible example but i scared that there is to little info on what i want

Comment: the one below is not really what i wanted

Answer (score 0, accepted):

someone helped me with this question from reddit

```
file=input('Enter file:')
f=file.split(".")
w=(f[0])
st=('st_' + w + '.dat')
from collections import defaultdict
src_map = defaultdict(dict)
in_test = False
subtest = None
with open(st,'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        if (line.strip() == '') : 
            #print ('blank line')
            continue
        if (not in_test) and not line.startswith("   subtest"): # skip
            print ('not in test, skip')
            continue
        elif re.match("\s+subtest\s+\"([^\"]+)\"",line):
            m = re.match("\s+subtest\s+\"([^\"]+)\"",line)
            subtest = m.group(1)
            print (f'found subtest {subtest} start')
            in_test = True
            continue
        elif (in_test) and ("end subtest" in line):
            print (f'found subtest {subtest} end')
            in_test = False
            subtest = None
            continue
        elif not (in_test):
            print ('not in test')
            continue
        else: # must be good line in LED subtest
            print ('good line')
            m = re.match(r"\s+wire\s+(\"[^\"]+\")\s+to\s+(\d+)\s+(aux alternate|aux|source|source alternate|detector high|detector low).*", line)
            if not m: # not a line we're interested in
                continue
            else:
                print (m)
                term1 = m.group(1)
                term2 = m.group(2)
                term3 = m.group(3)
                if term3.startswith('aux'):
                    src_map [subtest]['a'] = term1
                elif term3 == 'source' :
                    src_map [subtest]['s'] = term1
                elif term3.endswith('high'):
                    src_map [subtest]['i'] = term1
                else:
                    src_map [subtest]['l'] = term1
print(src_map)
       
#find the data that want to be replace
in_test = False
lines_out = []
with open(file,'r') as input_file:
    for line in input_file:
        #print (line)
        if (line.strip() == '') : 
            #print ('blank line')
            continue        
        if (not in_test) and not line.startswith('subtest'): # skip
            print ('not in test, skip')
            lines_out.append(line)
        elif re.match("subtest\s+\"([^\"]+)\"",line):
            m = re.match("subtest\s+\"([^\"]+)\"",line)
            subtest = m.group(1)
            print (f'found subtest {subtest} start')
            in_test = True
            lines_out.append(line)
        elif (in_test) and ("end subtest" in line):
            print (f'found subtest {subtest} end')
            in_test = False
            lines_out.append(line)
        elif not (in_test):
            print ('not in test')
            lines_out.append(line)
        else: # must be good line in LED subtest
            print ('good line')
            m = re.match(r"\s+connect\s+(\w)\s+to\s+pins\s+(\d).*", line)
            if not m: # not a line we're interested in
                lines_out.append(line)
            else:
                print (m)
                term1 = m.group(1)
                
                term2 = src_map[subtest][term1]
                new_line = f"   connect {term1} to nodes {term2}\n"
                lines_out.append(new_line)
                
with open('mynewfile.dat','a') as outfile:
    outfile.writelines(lines_out)
    outfile.close()

os.remove(st)
os.remove(file)
os.rename("mynewfile.dat",file)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can run loops in loops:

```
import re
#get data from wirelist.dat 
src_map = {}
in_test = False
with open(st,'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        for st in subtest:
            if (line.strip() == '') : 
                #print ('blank line')
                continue
            if (not in_test) and not re.match("\s+subtest\s+\""+st+"\"",line): # skip
                print ('not in test, skip')
                continue
            elif re.match("\s+subtest\s+\""+st+"\"",line):
                print ('found subtest start')
                in_test = True
                continue
            elif (in_test) and ("end subtest" in line):
                print ('found subtest end')
                in_test = False
                break
            elif not (in_test):
                print ('not in test')
                continue
            else: # must be good line in LED subtest
                print ('good line')
                m = re.match(r"\s+wire\s+(\"[^\"]+\")\s+to\s+(\d+)\s+(aux alternate|aux|source|source alternate|detector high|detector low).*", line)
                if not m: # not a line we are interested in
                    continue
                else:
                    print (m)
                    term1 = m.group(1)
                    term2 = m.group(2)
                    term3 = m.group(3)
                    if term3.startswith('aux'):
                        src_map ['a'] = term1
                    elif term3 == 'source' :
                        src_map ['s'] = term1
                    elif term3.endswith('high'):
                        src_map ['i'] = term1
                    else:
                        src_map['l'] = term1
print(src_map)
```